# How do I change eclipse so I don't have to manually import

Tags: java, eclipse, import

So to import in eclipse you press ctrl shift O. One problem is that some classes cannot be identified such as java.awt.Color; However If I ctrl click a class java.awt.color is opened. so I have to manually scroll up to the package copy paste the package, import then the error is resolved. Is this an eclipse problem, Should I change the SDK?

It's shit I have to keep doing it.

Comment: In Eclipse 2021-09 java.awt is filtered out of the imports - see the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can start typing

```java
import Color
```

and then hit Ctrl-Space for Content Assist, and choose `Color - java.awt` from the drop down.

Also works if you just start declaring a variable on any line where declarations are allowed

```java
    Color
```

and hit Ctrl-Space, and when you choose `Color - java.awt` the `import` statement will be added automatically.

Ctrl-Shift-O is for "Organize imports" and it is used to automatically re-arrange your existing imports. Sometimes this might result in adding an import for a class that you have already fully qualified in your code, but that's not the primary purpose of that function.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-09 filters out the java.awt imports, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Does it? Well I haven't seen that version, and if it does there might be a good reason. But on most versions you can check Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters.